# Adding a new classes in a function

Tags: python, function, class

Im making a calorie counting just for learing, as a beginner.
I wont to create def where i can choose the name(self) that will be enscrpted to the class, insert to this one name values in order to use them later but the value enscripted to class is not what i write as variable but just the name of the variable i gived in def.
I gived to def variable 'new' later making

```
 global x,
 x = new
```

and givining this x to class as a self. Here variable new is user1 so i wont x to be user1. I expected that when i try to use def from class it will be enscripcted as user1 not x, but its the opposite. here i have

```
user1.Body_information()
```

but it says:

```
NameError: name 'user1' is not defined. Did you mean: 'User'?
```

It would work though if there was

```
 x.Body_information()
```

But i  wont the (self) to be thing i written out in new_user(thing i wont as the self) so i could create new classes with this function.

[here is the class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCEH4.png)

[And here the](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efhOG.png) function

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFxqt.png)

At the beginning i just tried only with the variable 'new', without all the global x thing but it didint work at all then. I was thinking about counting the number of the def being called and based of the number of calls add this number to a value that would be enscrpited to class. (so it would be user1 on the frist call, user2 on the second call and so on) But i dont feel like im capable of doing that at least not alone and maybe there are easier way to do it so thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the whole code:

> Blockquote

```
class User:

  def __init__(self, name, weight, height, BMI, gender, age):
   self.weight_of_user = weight
   self.height_of_user = height
   self.BMI_of_user = BMI
   self.gender = gender
   self.age = age

  

def Body_information(self):
      print ('your weight is ' + str(self.weight_of_user))
      print ('your height is ' + str(self.height_of_user))
      print ('your BMI is ' + str(self.BMI_of_user))

def new_user(new):

 print('Welcome to the calorie counting program')
 name = input('choose a name')
 gendergiv = input('are you female or male?')
 if gendergiv != 'male' and gendergiv != 'female':
     print('Please chosse one of the two genders available')
     new_user(new)
 weightgiv = float(input('Please insert your weight'))
 heightgiv = float(input('Please insert your height (in meters)'))
 agegiv = int(input('Please insert your age'))
 BMIgiv = int(weightgiv / (heightgiv * heightgiv))
 global x
 x = new
 x = User(name = name, weight = weightgiv, height = heightgiv, BMI = BMIgiv, gender = gendergiv, age = agegiv)
 


new_user('user1')
user1.Body_information()
```

Comment: Are you interested in https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/476…‽

Comment: please provide a [mcve] in the question itself. it really isn't clear what you are doing

Comment: it *looks* like you are trying to dnyamically create variables. don't do that, there is never a good reason to do that. if you want to associate a string with an object, then make that association explicit, e.g., you can use a `dict` or some other data structure. variables *are for people reading the source code*, they shouldn't contain *program data*

Comment: in your function, `x = new` assigns a `str` object to the global variable `x`, which you then immediately overwrite by assigning it a `User` object on the next line. It does nothing useful and the program would be exactly equivalent if you removed the line. This is a common misconception for people beginning, *variables are not strings*.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and help. Using dict helped and solved my problem. Although im still not sure how variables work exacly i will read something about it so thank you again for help.

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but think of variables in mathematical terms. E.g. `E=mc²`. If you want to solve/"run" this equation, you *put in values for the variables*, like `E = 42 * 299792458²`. You do _not_ add new variables to the equation while you calculate it. You do not create new variable names on the fly in programming. Your *algorithm*, your program, uses variables which you have typed into the source code. The _values_ of these variables are the only thing that change at runtime.